# How do we norm the space of Fréchet differentiable functions from a Banach space $E$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, dual-spaces, frechet-derivative, signed-measures

Quick question, I couldn't find an answer to: If $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, and $C^1(E,\mathbb R)$ is the space of continuously Fréchet differentiable functions from $E$ to $\mathbb R$, how does one "usually" define a norm on $C^1(E,\mathbb R)$? I'd also be interested in Hölder spaces of functions from $E$ to $\mathbb R$, but all references I was able to find only consider $E=\mathbb R^d$.

Maybe there is some kind of duality to the space of signed measures which implicitly yields a norm.

**EDIT**: In particular, I'd like to show that if $d$ is a metric on $E$, equivalent to the canonical metric on $E$, and $\mu$ is a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$, then $$\left\|f\right\|:=\sup_{x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{d(x,y)}+\left|\int f\:{\rm d}\mu\right|$$ is a norm on $C^1(E,\mathbb R)$.

This kind of norm is considered in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1229696596) in equation (22) on p. 2063.

Comment: You can define the norm the same way, sup norm of the function plus sup norm of its derivative, but if $E$ is infinite dimensional many interesting functions, including the norm, are not Frechet differentiable. Signed measures on Banach spaces behave very poorly as well.

Comment: @Conifold Why do you think the norm is not Fréchet differentiable? If $E$ is a Hilbert space, then ${\rm D}\left\|x\right\|_E^2=2\langle x,\;\cdot\;\rangle_E$.

Comment: A norm arising from an inner product is always Frechet differentiable away from the origin, but the norm itself isn't differentiable at the origin, so definitely not an element of $C^1(E, \Bbb{R})$. Even worse is that an arbitrary norm on a Banach space can be badly behaved away from the origin (think for example the sum norm $(x,y) \mapsto |x| + |y|$ on $\Bbb{R}^2$).  But in addition to what @Conifold said, actually, if we don't restrict to functions with compact support, then there is no guarantee that the sup norm of function plus sup norm of derivative is finite (eg the exponential map).

Comment: @peek-a-boo What about the norm in my edit?

Comment: Hilbert spaces and certain reflexive spaces are better behaved than others, but think of $L^1$ or $L^\infty$ as more typical. Even on Hilbert spaces measure theory is subtle. To get the norm to be measurable you need measures  supported on extensions of the original space, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave aside any potential technicalities regarding how a probability measure on a Banach space is defined etc (because I really don't know enough measure theory to comment on that). **Also, it is not clear to me that the "norm" so defined takes a finite value for all $f$**. Aside from that, it seems like checking the other relevant properties of the norm is straight forward (but of course, take everything with a grain of salt, and perhaps someone else can provide their own answer/ suggest how to improve):

- It's clear that for all $f \in C^1(E, \Bbb{R})$, $\lVert f \rVert \geq 0$. Now, suppose that $\lVert f\rVert = 0$. Then, each summand defining $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ must be $0$. Fix an $x_0 \in E$, then, for all $y\neq x_0$, we have
  \begin{align}
  0 \leq \dfrac{|f(y) - f(x_0)|}{d(y, x_0)} \leq \sup_{y \neq x} \dfrac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{d(y, x)} = 0
  \end{align}
  Thus, $f(y) = f(x_0)$, which shows $f$ is constant on $E$. Next, $|\int_Ef \, d\mu| = 0$, together with the constancy of $f$, and the finiteness of the measure $\mu$ imply that the constant value for $f$ is actually $0$.
- It's fairly clear that for each $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$, $\lVert \lambda f\rVert = |\lambda| \cdot \lVert f\rVert$.
- Finally, the triangle inequality follows because it holds for the absolute value on $\Bbb{R}$. More explicitly, 
  \begin{align}
  \lVert f+ g\rVert &:= \sup_{x \neq y} \dfrac{|(f+g)(x) - (f+g)(y)|}{d(x,y)} + \left| \int_E (f+g) \, d\mu\right| \\
  &\leq \sup_{x \neq y}\left( \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{d(x,y)} + \dfrac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{d(x,y)} \right) + \left| \int_E f\right| + \left| \int_E g\right| \\
  &\leq \left[ \sup_{x \neq y}\left( \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{d(x,y)}\right) +\left| \int_E f\right| \right] + \left[ \sup_{x \neq y}\left( \dfrac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{d(x,y)}\right) +\left| \int_E g\right| \right] \\
  &= \lVert f \rVert + \lVert g \rVert.
  \end{align}

---

**Edit:**

Based on the comment provided, I corrected the argument for $\lVert f\rVert = 0 \implies f = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first summand in the definition of $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ is already a semi-norm which vanishes precisely for the constant functions. Now your conclusion $|\mu f|=0\Rightarrow f=0$ $\mu$-a.e. is wrong, unless $f$ is nonnegative. But due to the aforementioned result, we are still able to conclude (the even stronger result) $f=0$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d of course that was a very silly mistake (there were so many non-negative quantities, I just invoked that result implicitly assuming $f \geq 0$). I'll edit now. But the problem of the finiteness still remains though, and I'm not sure how to prove that.